# Unable to decode JSON stripslashed String?

Tags: php, json

Does anyone know why this happens?

```
var_dump(json_decode(stripslashes(json_encode(array("O'Reiley"))))); // array(1) { [0]=> string(8) "O'Reiley" } 
var_dump(json_decode(stripslashes(json_encode(array("O\'Reiley"))))); // NULL
```

Are `'` used at all by the JSON functions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know for sure, but [**json_last_error()**](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) should :)

My guess, though, is that `json_encode()` does something to the `\'` that the `stripslashes()` then breaks - e.g. add another "\" to escape the backslash.

Isn't fiddling with a json encoded string using `striplslashes()` before it's decoded wrong anyway?

Comment: First time I'm gonna use that function! Yey!

Comment: Can you dump the json_encoded string from the second line (without stripslashes)?

Comment: You're right: `["O\\'Reiley"]` could have just ignored it since it uses `"` and not `'`. There goes my super cool anti magic quotes method. =(

Comment: what did you do to resolve that problem, i'm having same issue here. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I didn't look at it too deeply, but it looks like your code is

1. Taking a PHP Array and turning it into a json string
2. Mucking with that string
3. Trying to decode the mucked string as json

Think of it like this

```
$json_string = json_encode(array("O\'Reiley");
$json_string = stripslashes($json_string);      

//it's no longer json, its just some random non-conforming string
var_dump(json_decode($json_string))
```

Comment: Yeah, my though was that JSON didn't used `'` and thus had no reason to escape it. I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You should try without stripslashes()

```
$result = json_encode(striptslashes(array("O\'Reiley")));
if(json_last_error() > 0){
   $result = json_encode(array("O\'Reiley"));
}
```